# Need help to figure out how to position the button correctly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, game-development

I am currently working on a trivia game for my programming class.
Most things work as intended, but I can't figure out how to position the *button* **time** correctly.

The button moves out of it's space: 
[Trivia Game Button Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/571iL.png)

This is a bit confusing to me, as it worked perfectly before uploading it to github. I also wasn't able to resolve this error.

Here the HTML code, which includes the bootstrap4 classes:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" id="buttonHit">Start the Game </button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary mb-2 float-right noHover">Time: <span class="badge badge-primary" id="time">00:30</span></button>
        <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active question" id="question" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">Click "Start" to start the game</a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action answerBtn1 answerBtn" id="answer1" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile"></a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action answerBtn2 answerBtn" id="answer2" data-toggle="list" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages"></a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action answerBtn3 answerBtn" id="answer3" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings"></a>
            <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action answerBtn4 answerBtn" id="answer4" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I hardly used any additional CSS

```
.noHover{
    pointer-events: none;
}

.h1Margin {
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
```

The entire game you can find on [github](https://saschaschneider.github.io/TriviaGame/)

I am curious to learn what I can do better to position the button correctly.

Thanks you all!

Comment: I see what you don't want, but how do you want the button to look/be positioned?

Answer (score 1):

For the button, you can use relative position and then give relative position from top or bottom ( left or right ) to place wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's doing exactly what you told it to do:

- The container is `col-md-4`
- The time button is floated to the right

I don't know how you wanted things to look right, but you can make it look better by either:

1. Making the `#list-tab` to [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) the floated element (`clear: both;`)
2. Unfloat the time button by removing the `float-right` class from it.

Comment: Makes sense. I just don't understand why it doesn't align with the element underneath. I want the left button to be aligned with the left side and the right button with the right side. But at the moment the right button is too far out...why is it floating so far right?

Comment: It floats correctly (all the way to the right side of its container). When you float an element to one side, the next elements, by default, will stay clear off the vertical space created by the floating element. You can use the `clear` property to change that behavior.